# Using the paint or repaint method to paint lines over an applet JAVA

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt, paint

I am wondering if it's possible to paint lines over an applet. I am loading the applet from an external source, but I'd like to paint lines where the cursor is on the screen.

Can someone tell me how I'd do this please?

Here's an example.

```
  g.drawLine(mouse.getLocation().x - 6, mouse.getLocation().y,
            mouse.getLocation().x + 6, mouse.getLocation().y);
            g.drawLine(mouse.getLocation

            ().x, mouse.getLocation().y - 6,


            mouse.getLocation().x, mouse.getLocation().y + 6);
```

Comment: 1. use JApplet 2. put there JPanel 3. override paintComponent for JPanel, 4. read [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html), 5. read related (this site on right side, bellow carrers icon), 6. post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) if without success

Comment: I can't seem to use JApplet to load it. It can't be cast to JApplet apparently

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering if it's possible to paint lines over an applet.

Sure you can. Simply put a panel in the applet, add a mouse motion listener and draw on that panel according to the events.

Small example illustrating this

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestAppletDraw extends JApplet {

    public static class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {

        private List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();

        public MyDrawPanel() {
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            MouseAdapter listener = new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    points.clear();
                    repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    points.add(e.getPoint());
                    repaint();
                }
            };
            addMouseListener(listener);
            addMouseMotionListener(listener);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 300);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Point p1 = null;
            Point p2 = null;
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            for (Point p : points) {
                p2 = p1;
                p1 = p;
                if (p1 != null && p2 != null) {
                    g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void initUI() {
        add(new MyDrawPanel());
        validate();
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    initUI();
                }
            });
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

NB: Using a buffered image instead of storing points may be more scalable over long periods of time (otherwise the points List can become gigantic) but it requires to take care of panel size increases.

Comment: [crossposted:-)](http://www.coderanch.com/t/607872/GUI/java/Painting-mouse-movement-applet)

Comment: Not crossposting anything? I'm asking on another forum because you guys aren't replying...

Comment: @user2059879 Nobody is replying because you don't provide information that allows to help you. Stating "It does not work for me" may be a true statement, but it hardly gives us any evidence of what the problem is or could be. One easy way to help us and yourself is to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) such as the one I have posted in my answer.

Comment: there no reason to post any reply, to questions of this nature, as you can to see on another forum too